# Download a file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, download

I'm trying to download a PowerPoint file. I'm saving its path in column `slide` in a table called `lesson`. Whenever I try to download it, it downloads the whole table.

All I want is the column `slide`, how can I do that?

```
// connect to the database
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect :' . mysql_error());
}

$Selected= mysql_select_db("elearningg", $link);

if (!$Selected) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

// query the server for the file
$L_ID = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE LID = '$L_ID'";
$result  = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// define results into variables
$name=mysql_result($result,0,"Lname");
$content=mysql_result($result,0,"slide");

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$name");

echo $content;

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Again another user using Evil **`mysql_* `** . Please Stop it !!

Comment: if I used mysqli_ it'll be fixed?

Comment: i'm not sure about the way I wrote the code

Comment: _"it download the whole table"_  what table? _"all I want is the column slide"_ you mean, you want to extract that particular slide from the file?

Comment: What is a column slide?

Comment: He means the column's name is `slide`.

Comment: (slide is a folder ) contains files and i want the file that belongs to a specific lesson name that why i'm saving it in the same table

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: well then, if `$content` is the name of the folder, and `$name` is the name of the file, then you may change the arguments to the `header` function to `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$content/$name");`

Comment: use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the column `slide`, you have to select only that column in your select clause. Right now you're selecting all of the table's columns by using `SELECT *`.

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT slide FROM lesson WHERE LID = '$L_ID'";
```

That should only return the column `slide` from table `lesson`.

Comment: Yes, but I see in your code that you're also using the column `Lname`, so you should probably do `SELECT slide, Lname FROM lesson`.